# unable to render view on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

When clicking on "a" anchor tag I want to redirect from one controller(HomeController.cs) to another controller(CartController.cs) index [GET] and and execute code and return data to view(cart/index.cshtml).

Here is the js code

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-margin', function () {
        if (parseInt($('#UserID').val()) > 0) {
            var pmID = $(this).attr("id"),
                bid = $(this).attr("brand-id");
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("index", "cart")',
                data: { "id": pmID, "bid" : bid },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                }
            });
        }           
    });
```

and in CartController

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(long id = 0, long bid = 0)
{
     GetStates();
     return View(productBL.GetProductById(id, bid));
}
```

As expected it has to redirect to index.cshtml of cart.. but my result is still in homeController of index.cshtml page.

Please help me out how to get the expected result..

Comment: Did you try adding  return RedirectToAction("Index", "CartController"); in your home controller ?

Comment: I need to pass parameters to that action

Comment: try this - return RedirectToAction("Index", "CartController", new{ id: pmId})

Answer (score 0):

you don't need an ajax call for this.
on you 'a' click use something like this

```
$('.btn-margin').on('click',function(){
 if (parseInt($('#UserID').val()) > 0) {
            var pmID = $(this).attr("id"),
            var   bid = $(this).attr("brand-id");
            window.location.href = "/cart/index?id="+pmID+"&bid=" +bid;
          }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: this displays the parameters in the url.. I am trying through ajax-call to avoid this.. @karthik

Comment: @thiru if you have class or id to container within which your view is rendered.. then on success you can do this $(" id or class of container").html(response)

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX call, you define this:

```
$.ajax({
       dataType: 'json',
```

But your controller action returns HTML, not JSON:

```
public ActionResult Index(long id = 0, long bid = 0)
    return View(productBL.GetProductById(id, bid));
```

It should return data using the Json method:

```
   return Json(prodcutBL.GetProductById(id, bid), JsonBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The second parameter indicates a GET request is allowed (normally POST is required only, and otherwise would throw an exception).  This will return a JSON object to the success callback, and then you can access the data like normal.  You might want to return an object directly, instead of an array, like:

```
   return Json(new { products = prodcutBL.GetProductById(id, bid) }, JsonBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And then in your callback access it like:

```
success: function (response) {
     if (response.products.length == 0)
        alert("No data available");
     else /* do something */
            },
```

Microsoft recommends [returning an object, not an array, for a web response.](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

try this - `return RedirectToAction("Index", "CartController", new{ id: pmId})`